# Google calendar in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am creating an application in which I need to embed Google Calander. I have installed the CefSharp framework and have added a link so that it opens Google Calander into a panel but once the login credentials have been entered it gives me an error saying that the 'browser or app may not be secure'. Is there any way I can get around this?

This is my code:

```
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings { CachePath = "MyCachePath", PersistSessionCookies = true });
        string cache_dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
        settings.CachePath = cache_dir;
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1");
        string link = "https://www.google.com/calendar/render";
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(link);
        this.Calander.Controls.Add(chrome);
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

This is the error:

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Where does the "Learn More" link take you?

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16764